# IValueConverter with error handling

Tags: wpf, validation, data-binding, converters

I know this is a pretty broad problem, so I'm surprised I haven't found a good answer yet. Here's my situation:

I have a class named TimeConverter that I use quite often, which implements the IValueConverter interface converts a string containing an amount of time (such as "25:36") into an integer representing the number of minutes (which for the earlier example would be 1536). Currently, when someone enters something untranslatable (like "asdf") the converter returns DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, which causes the bound element (usually a TextBox) to show a red border. Here's the problem, the class containing the integer property on the other end of the binding needs to know that there is a conversion error.

I've found this to be quite difficult and almost impossible to do without the data item having a reference to the bound TextBox. If I get a reference to the TextBox, I can use the Validation attached properties, but i feel like that's sloppy and its also not always possible. Currently I have one of these bindings in place on a TextBox, inside a Setter, inside a Style, inside a DataTemplate (pretty far removed from the visual tree), which also prevents me from using the Validation.Error even for notification. And of course the simple answer of binding Validation.HasError to the data item doesn't work because of how the property is declared.

So how CAN I notify the data item when the conversion fails?

Comment: Simplest solution: Dont use `IValueConverter`. Instead implement `IDataErrorInfo`. WPF's validation-machanism will do the rest

Comment: @lokusking But then how do I implement the type conversion from string to integer?